# declaration of array size as a[N+1]

Tags: c, arrays

The code defines array  like this-

```
#define N 100 
long int mid[N+1]
```

Here whether `mid[N+1]=mid[100+1]` i.e `mid[101]`?
Also I want to know can we declare array of 2 elements as `int n[1+1]`?

Answer (score 2):

starting from the second question , yes, you can declare something like `mid[2+1]`  , because you are declaring an array of literal size (3 being the literal), and not a variable size.

that brings us to the first question. Yes, it's the same. at an early phase of the compilation, the compiler takes all the definitions in the code and "expands" them to the defined value or expression, so `mid[N+1]` turns literally into `mid[100+1]`.

note that the `N` here, is a defined value and not a variable. you can't declare `mid[N+1]` if that `N` is a variable (not until C99 i think).

Answer (score 0):

```
#define N 100 
long int mid[N+1]
```

That's perfectly valid (apart from the missing semicolon), and equivalent to

```
long int mid[101];
```

The length of an array can be any integer constant expression with a positive value. It doesn't have to be an integer constant (literal).

Similarly,

```
int n[1+1];
```

is equivalent to

```
int n[2];
```

(At block scope, an array defined without the `static` keyword can have a variable length, which can be specified by any integer expression. (If the value of the expression is not positive, the behavior is undefined.)  Variable length arrays are not permitted in C90; they were introduced in C99, and support for them was made optional by C11, so not all compilers support them.)

Answer (score -1):

You can declare array like this,Array size should be positive.

```
#define N 100 
long int mid[N+1]
```

if you want to use array of length N+1,
you can use *malloc* also

```
malloc();
```

eg,

```
 #define N 100 
 long int* mid;

 int main()
 {
  mid = malloc((N+1)*sizeof(long int));
  return 0;
 }
```

So you can access array **mid** of size **101**.

Comment: Yes, you can. Any (positive) integer constant expression is valid as an array length. `long int mid[N+1];` is perfectly valid.

Comment: `malloc` doesn't seem relevant; since `N+1` is constant, it's not necessary.